# PDO DBLib not working

Tags: sql-server, pdo

I have a connection with the DBLIB PDO driver, and I am not getting any errors on connecting, but when I run a query an exception is thrown with the error below. I have played around with the syntax of the query as well. I am connecting to a MS SQL server:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 208 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [SELECT PCO_INBOUNDLOG.PHONE FROM PCO_INBOUNDLOG]
```

The code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT PCO_INBOUNDLOG.PHONE FROM PCO_INBOUNDLOG";
 foreach($this->mssql->query($sql) as $row) {
      print_r($row);
 }
```

This is the first time I have ever done a query to a MS SQL server so my syntax may be wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find out what error 208 means:

```
select * from sys.messages where message_id = 208
```

Second, check the [FROM syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) (including the examples!) and [object identifier rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Third, write the query correctly:

```
SELECT PHONE FROM PCO_INBOUNDLOG
```

Or, probably better (because it's good practice to include the schema name):

```
SELECT PHONE FROM dbo.PCO_INBOUNDLOG
```

Or even:

```
SELECT p.PHONE FROM dbo.PCO_INBOUNDLOG p
```