# SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9) error on Ubuntu Linux VPS

Tags: php, sql-server, azure

I am trying to connect to an Azure Microsoft SQL Server database on my php scripts. I cannot figure out why it isn't working. When I run my db_connection.php script, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

When I run the tsql command, with the connection details for my azure ms sql database, the connection seems to work (I read the "1>" means the connection worked):

```
locale is "C"
locale charset is "ANSI_X3.4-1968"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Default database being set to iBalekaDB
1>
```

Inside my freetds.conf file, I have this configuration set up:

```
# server specific section
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
        tds version = 8.0
        text size = 20971520
        client charset = UTF-8

        dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
        debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10


[iBalekaServer]
        host = xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.windows.net
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

My db_connection.php file looks like this:

```
try {

    $dataSource = "dblib:host=iBalekaServer;dbname=iBalekaDB;";
    $username = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

    $connectionObject = new PDO($dataSource, $username, $password);
    $connectionObject->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if ($connectionObject) {
        echo "<h2>Connection Successful</h2>";
    } else {
        echo "Connection Error";
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I ran tsql -C on the VPS and got this:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                            Version: freetds v0.91
             freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
     MS db-lib source compatibility: no
        Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                      Thread safety: yes
                      iconv library: yes
                        TDS version: 4.2
                              iODBC: no
                           unixodbc: yes
              SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                           Kerberos: yes
```

I checked to see if I had pdo_dblib installed, and it was present when I ran phpinfo() on my Linux VPS Server.

What could be the issue here?

**EDIT: using mssql_connect works. I really wanted to use PDO**

Answer (score 1):

On my test, I changed the `$username` to the format of `UID` (e.g. `<username>@<db_server_name>`), and it fixed your issue of `SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)`.

BTW, you can grab the `UID` from the connectionstring from Azure portal.

Additionally, if you get the issue of `General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 16)`, you can refer to the answer of [PDO DBLib not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914008/pdo-dblib-not-working).

Any update, please feel free to let me know.